# NSMutableArray Not Retaining Objects Outside Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

In my `-viewDidLoad` method, I initialize many `NSMutableDictionaries`, and add them to an initialized `NSMutableArray` declared via `@property` in the class header file. The relevant code is shown below. In short, I'm webscraping information from an HTML webpage.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
_regionalDicts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [strings count]; i++) {
    NSString *str = [strings objectAtIndex:i];
    //Property parser:
    if ([str rangeOfString:@"<td>"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *parsedTD1 = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<td>" withString:@""];
        NSString *parsedTD2 = [parsedTD1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</td>" withString:@""];
        NSString *parsedTD3 = [parsedTD2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@"\n"];


        NSString *final = [parsedTD3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];

        //NSLog(@"Final string: %@", final);

        if ([final isEqualToString:@""]) {
            continue;
        }


        if (gotEventType == NO) {
            gotEventType = YES;
            [dict setObject:final forKey:@"type"];
            continue;
        }

        if (gotRegional == YES && gotLocation == NO) {
            gotLocation = YES;
            [dict setObject:final forKey:@"location"];
            continue;
        }
        if (gotLocation == YES && gotCity == NO) {
            gotCity = YES;
            NSString *cityToReturn = [final stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
            [dict setObject:cityToReturn forKey:@"city"];
            continue;
        }     
        if (gotRegional == YES && gotEventType == YES && gotCity == YES && gotLocation == YES && gotURL == YES) {
            gotRegional = NO;
            gotEventType = NO;
            gotCity = NO;
            gotLocation = NO;
            gotURL = NO;

            NSLog(@"Regional: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"regional"]);
            NSLog(@"Type: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"type"]);
            NSLog(@"City: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"city"]);

            //Testing to see if anything is nil
            NSLog(@"Location: %@\n", [dict objectForKey:@"location"]);
            if (!_regionalDicts) {
                NSLog(@"Dict is nil");
            }
            [_regionalDicts addObject:dict];
            NSLog(@"Objects in array: %u", [_regionalDicts count]);
            NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [_regionalDicts objectAtIndex:[_regionalDicts count]-1];
            NSLog(@"Regional in array: %@", [tempDict objectForKey:@"regional"]);
            [dict removeAllObjects];

            continue;
        }
```

It's clear that the generated dictionaries are generated and retained within the `_regionalDicts` mutable array, which is declared in the header file like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *regionalDicts;
```

However, when I attempt to pass in information to table view cells in in the same class, the dictionaries' contents are null. There are as many objects within the array as dictionaries I am expecting, but they do not contain any content.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (_regionalDicts) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [_regionalDicts objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Setting label %@", [dict objectForKey:@"city"]);
        [cell.textLabel setText:[dict objectForKey:@"regional"]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Returns:

```
2013-04-01 19:58:50.250 MatchScrape[53570:207] Setting label (null)
```

I can only imagine that a memory management issue is to blame. Why would the contents of a class array be nullified when accessed outside the scope of the method they are added in, but allow the array to retain the same count?

Comment: `[dict removeAllObjects];` -- That would tend to remove everything from the dictionary.

Comment: Correct, but not until after it's been added to the array.

Comment: The point of clearing the dictionary was to allow the for loop to reutilize the same dictionary instance.

Comment: Right, you added the dictionary to the array, then removed all its entries.  It's like writing a check and then stopping payment on it.

Comment: (You need to create a new instance every time.  Adding an object to an array or dictionary does not create a copy of it, it just copies it's address.)

Comment: (Please, please, please ... Don't try to write anything resembling a real app until you understand programming in general and Objective-C in particular a ***lot*** better.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to believe that adding the dictionary to the array doesn't actually add the dictionary to the array, but instead adds a *copy* of the dictionary. You're probably thinking of how it might work in a language like C++ — but that isn't how it works here. Remember, Objective-C objects are always accessed by reference: you never directly store the object itself in a variable or array — you're just shuffling around a pointer to the actual object, which usually lives on the heap.

So when you add `_dict` to the array, the one in the array is the very same object referenced by `_dict`. Anything you do to that dictionary — no matter what reference you use — will be reflected everywhere else that dictionary is referenced, because it's the same dictionary. You haven't made a copy of it. Thus, when you do `[_dict removeAllObjects]`, that removes all the objects from the dictionary and you end up with an array that contains the same empty dictionary a bunch of times.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the clear explanation. Turns out that was the exact thought process I employed which brought about the issue. I seemed to be thinking about objects in the way they're viewed in Java. Thanks again.

Comment: @TheKraken - Java treats objects the exact same way.

Comment: Is that true for both objects and primitives?

Comment: @TheKraken: Primitives that are accessed through pointers, yes — several pointers can all reference the same memory, whether that memory is an object, a primitive or complete garbage. The thing about objects is that they're always accessed through pointers, whereas it's possible to actually have a raw `int`.